# Listview with checkbox: column order changes checkbox position

Tags: c#, listview, checkbox

In C# Windows Forms I have a listview with the CheckBoxes property set to true and the AllowColumnReorder property set to true.

The checkbox for each item is shown at the very left-hand side of the listview inside the first column. If the user now reorders the columns so that another column is the first one of the listview, the checkbox should be shown for this column. So the checkbox should always stay at the very left-hand side of the listview, but it doesn't buy default.

What do I need to do, to always show the checkbox for the leftmost column even if the column order was changed by the user at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understant.

You put Checkboxes, aside another element into a column?

If yes, why don't you add a column , only for your checkbox, and then set Reorder property to false?

The others columns will always have Reorder property to true, so you can shamble whatever you want, exept the first column.

Comment: The [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx) control has the property [CheckBoxes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.checkboxes.aspx) which I set to true because I want a checkbox to be displayed for each row. I also want the user to be able moving the columns, therefore I set the property called [AllowColumnReorder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.allowcolumnreorder.aspx) to true.

Comment: The problem is, that the checkbox is always shown at the very left hand side of the row (which is perfectly fine) but if the user moves another column to the first position (so that this column is now the leftmost one), the position of the checkbox is not updated. This means that the checkbox is now somewhere inbetween the columns which doesn't look that nice.